# Segmentation fault while accessing vector elements

Tags: c++, reference, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access

I am learning how to make a reference variable in C++ and I am having some trouble when using `int &res = f[k]` to make `res` a variable that refers to a given component of vector `f`.

In this code `F(k)` should return the fibonacci number of integer input `k` computed by memorizing the previous calls `F(0)`, `F(1)`,... `F(k-2)` and `F(k-1)` in vector `f` but I get a `Segmentation Fault` which makes me think I fail to refer `res` as a component of vector `f`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int UNDEF = -1;
vector<int> f;

int F(int k) {
  int &res = f[k];  // I get "res: 0x0000000000000004 and &res: ??" when debugging
  if (res != UNDEF) return res; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4)
  if (k <= 1) return 1;
  return res = F(k-1) + F(k-2);
}

int main() {
  int k;
  cin >> k;
  vector<int> f(k+1, UNDEF);
  cout << F(k) << endl;
}
```

I could really use some help over here! Thanks a lot:)

Àlex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global vector variable `f` has *no elements*. And when you write:

```
int &res = f[k];
```

You're trying to access it's `k`th element which doesn't exist which is why you get **segmentation fault** at that point.

Note in your program you have two vector variable with the same name `f`. One of them is a local variable while the other one is a global variable.

When you write

```
int &res = f[k];
```

The vector `f` that is chosen is the global variable and since the global vector `f` has size 0(empty vector), when you try to access its `k`th element it gives you segmentation fault(**undefined behavior**) as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ckv8vMzwlQ14iEHk).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were totally right :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I got an answer that was later deleted but this was the easiest solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int UNDEF = -1;

int F(int k, vector<int>& f) {
  int &res = f[k];  
  if (res != UNDEF) return res;
  if (k <= 1) return 1;
  return res = F(k-1, f) + F(k-2, f);
}

int main() {
  int k;
  cin >> k;
  vector<int> f(k+1, UNDEF);
  cout << F(k, f) << endl;
}
```